# scapy PcapReader cut short

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I'm trying to rewrite a pcap file with different IP and IPv6 addresses. But after I extract a packt by PcapReader and change its IP adresses, the packets in the output pcap file is cut short (that is to say the payload of the packet is lost).
Here's the example code:

```
from scapy.all import PcapReader
from scapy.all import PcapWriter

def test():
    f = "input.pcap"
    writers = PcapWriter("output.pcap")

    with PcapReader(f) as pcap_reader:
        for pkt in pcap_reader:
            # somehow change the IP address
            writers.write(pkt=pkt)

test()
```

When I open the .pcap file with WireShark, it shows "The capture file appears to have been cut short in the middle of a packet". 
Is there any solution in scapy to maintain the payload or is there any other python packets to recommand?

here I did not change anything and the results are like this:
input file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxfuA.png)

output file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwkU9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem must be in the code you use to modify the packet (and which you did not show) or that your source file already had short packets (i.e. snaplen less than packet len). The following code works for me without problems:

```
from scapy.all import PcapReader,PcapWriter,IP
writer = PcapWriter('output.pcap')
for pkt in PcapReader('input.pcap'):
    # somehow change the IP address
    pkt[IP].dst = '1.2.3.4'
    pkt[IP].src = '5.6.7.8'
    writer.write(pkt=pkt)
```

Comment: I actually did not change anything yet at the place of comment. Just read it by PcapReader and rewrite with PcapWriter to another file. And you can check the pictures I uploaded. The length of the packet was changed.

Comment: @Awdrtg: your input file has shortened packets where the original packet length is less than what was captured (*"packet size limited during capture"*). Starting with such a broken capture you just another broken capture, just differently broken. Make sure that you capture full packets to avoid this problem.

Comment: All right. By the way I'm wondering how to change the IPv6 address?

Comment: @Awdrtg: Your original question is answered. Please don't ask new questions like *"... how to change the IPv6 address..."* inside a comment but instead create a new question.